# javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS

Tags: java, sockets, email, ssl

I have enother **convert socket** exception. Stackoverflow linked me to related answer and i have done everything people suggest there.

Here we have exception description :

> Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
>     nested exception is:
>       java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing 
>            implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class:
>           sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
>       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1880)
>       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:648)
>       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
>       at XMailMessenger.MailMessenger.sendMail(MailMessenger.java:414)
>       at alfa.runner.main(runner.java:38)
>           Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error
>            constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class:
>           sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
>       at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:432)
>       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1875)
>       ... 4 more
>           Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation
>           (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class:
>           sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
>       at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:427)
>       ... 5 more
>          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.getDefaultKeyManager(Unknown
>           Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       ... 12 more

So i decide to write 2 additional classes:

```
      package XMailMessenger;

     import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
     import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
     /**
      * @author Raminderjeet Singh
      */
      public class DummyTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

      public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] cert, String authType) {
    // everything is trusted


   }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] cert, String authType) {
   // everything is trusted
   }

   public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
      return new X509Certificate[0];
   }
   }
```

and the second one:

```
 package XMailMessenger;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.net.InetAddress;
  import java.net.Socket;

  import javax.net.SocketFactory;
   import javax.net.ssl.*;

  /**
  * @author Raminderjeet Singh
 */
  public class DummySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
   private SSLSocketFactory factory;

    public DummySSLSocketFactory() {
try {
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslcontext.init(null,
             new TrustManager[] { new DummyTrustManager()},
             null);
    factory = (SSLSocketFactory)sslcontext.getSocketFactory();
} catch(Exception ex) {
    // ignore
}
}

public static SocketFactory getDefault() {
return new DummySSLSocketFactory();
}

public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
return factory.createSocket();
}

public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String s, int i, boolean flag)
            throws IOException {
return factory.createSocket(socket, s, i, flag);
}

   public Socket createSocket(InetAddress inaddr, int i,
            InetAddress inaddr1, int j) throws IOException {
return factory.createSocket(inaddr, i, inaddr1, j);
    }

   public Socket createSocket(InetAddress inaddr, int i)
            throws IOException {
 return factory.createSocket(inaddr, i);
   }

  public Socket createSocket(String s, int i, InetAddress inaddr, int j)
            throws IOException {
  return factory.createSocket(s, i, inaddr, j);
   }

  public Socket createSocket(String s, int i) throws IOException {
  return factory.createSocket(s, i);
  }

  public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
  return factory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
  }

    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return factory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
   }
  }
```

Finally we have method to send mail:

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", currentSettingsDocument.getSMTPHostServer());
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", currentSettingsDocument.getLogin());
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", currentSettingsDocument.getPassword());
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.timeout" , "3000");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");

    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("javax.net.debug","ssl,session");

    // Required to avoid security exception.
        Authenticator authentication = new Authenticator() {
          protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
             return new PasswordAuthentication(currentSettingsDocument.getLogin() , 
            currentSettingsDocument.getPassword());  
          }
         };
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authentication);
    // create some properties and get the default Session

    // create a message
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    // set the from and to address
    InternetAddress addressFrom = new    


       InternetAddress(currentSettingsDocument.getSenderMail());
   msg.setFrom(addressFrom);


       for(InternetAddress addr: recepients )
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, addr );

    // Optional : You can also set your custom headers in the Email if you
    // 
    // msg.addHeader("MyHeaderName", "myHeaderValue");

    // Setting the Subject and Content Type
    msg.setContent("1111", "text/plain");
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            Document.getSMTPHostServer(), Document.getPassword());
    transport.connect(currentSettingsDocument.getSMTPHostServer(), 465,                                 
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
```

And after calling **sendMessage** i get exception :

> окт 18, 2013 5:36:18 PM XMailMessenger.MailMessenger sendMail
>   SEVERE: null
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
>     nested exception is:
>       java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

PS Google mail works properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is caused by the unsupported **TLS** on old Windows (XP, Vista) and thrown by the class SocketFetcher (package com.sun.mail.util;) at line

```
MailSSLSocketFactory msf = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
```

and MailSSLSocketFactory (same package) `/**
     * Initializes a new MailSSLSocketFactory.
     * 
     * @throws  GeneralSecurityException
     */
    public MailSSLSocketFactory() throws GeneralSecurityException {
    this("TLS");
    }`

Comment: what is the solution for this?